# Why does the generator in python not return anything when i use recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, generator

I am currently working on a code that finds paths from one airport to another by giving me every path that I can take in a list. The airports are in a dictionary which looks like this:
`airports = {"ATL": {"lat": 33.6407, "lon": -84.4277},#and so on`
I already implemented another code that calculates the distance of two places called haversine. The flights individually shouldn't have a distance of more than the amount i give through a parameter. More information is in the docstring of my code.

```
def find_paths(airports: dict, start: str, end: str, max_distance: int, path=None):
    """
    Generates all possible paths between two airports within a given maximum distance.

    This function is a generator that yields all the paths from a starting airport to an ending         airport. Each path is constrained by a maximum distance between consecutive airports in the path. The function uses recursion and backtracking to explore all potential paths.

    Args:
    airports (dict): A dictionary where keys are airport codes and values are dictionaries containing 'lat' and 'lon' keys for latitude and longitude.
    start (str): The airport code representing the starting airport.
    end (str): The airport code representing the destination airport.
    max_distance (float): The maximum distance allowed between two consecutive airports in the path.
    path (list): The current path being explored. Defaults to an empty list.

    Yields:
    list: A list of airport codes representing a valid path from start to end within the maximum       distance constraints.
    """
    if path is None:
        path = [start]
    
    if path==end:
        yield path
        
    for i in airports:
        if i not in path:
            distance = haversine((airports[start]["lat"],airports[start]["lon"]),((airports[i]["lat"],airports[i]["lon"])))
            if distance<=max_distance:
                yield from find_paths(airports, i, end, max_distance, path+[i])
                
for i in find_paths(airports,"ATL","SIN",5000):
    print(i)
```

I think that the recursion is currently making a generator each time the function recurves. So i tried doing it without recursion but I am not sure how to do that. I tried not using a "from" after my yield, but then I only got Generator objects instead of the list I wanted.

Comment: I only removed the "from" and used yield find_paths(airports, i, end, max_distance, path+[i]) instead, but it resulted in even more confusion.

Comment: What values of `airports` are you using? Hard to test without some data. And maybe use a built in distance function for testing. But the problem is probably `if path==end`. Your `path` is an array of codes, but `end` is a string. It does the looping but doesn't hit your end condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A valid path is found when the starting airport is the same as the ending airport, not when the path itself is the same as the ending airport. You should also avoid continuing the search past a valid path by putting the search in an `else` block:

Change:

```
if path==end:
    yield path

for i in airports:
    ...
```

to:

```
if start == end:
    yield path
else:
    for i in airports:
        ...
```

Comment: I tried that now and at first I thought nothing changed but once i changed the max_distance in my test from 5000 to 6000 it started working out. Thank you very much.